# Do I need travel insurance for France on an Airport Transit Schengen Visa?

Tags: visas, france, paris, insurance, transit-visas

I'm Indian and have an Indian passport and I'm travelling to Chile. I have a 6 hours layover at France have an Airport Transit Schengen visa. Do I need a travel insurance?

Will I be allowed if I don't have a travel insurance?

Comment: http://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/en/coming-to-france/getting-a-visa/article/what-type-of-visa-do-i-need-to - this site doesn't mention a requirement of a health insurance, so I think that you don't need one. However I cannot be 100% sure.

Comment: It is not mandatory but a good idea to have a travel insurance when outside India. Take bajaj allianz travel insurance. It should cover you for medical expenses, trip cancelation, lost passport, lost baggage etc.. You can buy for INR 4000 approx per trip. Please note maximum 180 days coverage. You should buy it when in India and once you arrrive back in India, the policy expires. I always take one when abroad. I am indian too and have visited over 32 EU member states and lived 5 years in Europe..

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a travel insurance if you have air transit visa for France and if you are Indian (not sure about other countries). But its always good to have a travel insurance, you never know when you will need it.

I did have a travel insurance but it was invalid as I had postponed my flight and the departure dates were of the previous flights.

When I reached France they only checked my air transit visa and the Chile visa and didn't ask for a travel insurance or the euros I had.

**Update :**

Sorry for not mentioning this.

I had spoken with [VFS Global](http://www.vfsglobal.com/), an company authorized to collect visa documents and collecting biometric scans on whether I need a travel insurance and they said it was not necessary. Again its advisable to ask the consulate or the visa issuing authority before taking any decision.

Airport Transit: applies in case you have to change flights without leaving the airport or going through immigration control.

**Mandatory Documents:**

- Original passport valid for a minimum period of three months after
  the expiry date of the visa (passports issued more than ten years ago
  are no longer accepted)* and 1 old passport if applicable plus one
  copy of the first and last page of the current passport. The passport
  should have 2 blank pages.
- One application form with all columns
  filled in and 2 recent photographs not older than 6 months. The
  photograph must measure 35 mm in width by 45 mm in length. The length
  of face must be 32 to 36 mm from bottom of chin to the top of the
  skull (Besides hair), that is, the face coverage has to be 60-70 % of
  the photo./
- Original covering letter
- Copy of visa of final destination
- Copy of air ticket

Source : [VFS Global](http://www.vfs-france.co.in/airporttransitdocuments.html)

Comment: The application for a visa typically always asks for some proof of insurance, what makes you say you don't need one for a transit visa, do you have a reference for this ?

Comment: @blackbird57 Thanks for bringing up the point. See my updated answer.

Comment: @blackbird57 A Schengen airport transit visa is valid only for passengers who will not leave the international transit area of the airport.  In other words, they will not pass through passport control.  I suppose it's not considered necessary to require insurance because they won't be in the jurisdiction of a Schengen country for more than a few hours.

Answer (score 5):

The travel insurance requirement derives from article 15 of the [Schengen visa code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02009R0810-20131018), which reads:

> 1. Applicants for a uniform visa for one or two entries shall prove that they are in possession of adequate and valid travel medical insurance to cover any expenses which might arise in connection with repatriation for medical reasons, urgent medical attention and/or emergency hospital treatment or death, during their stay(s) on the territory of the Member States.
> 2. Applicants for a uniform visa for more than two entries (multiple entries) shall prove that they are in possession of adequate and valid travel medical insurance covering the period of their first intended visit.
>
> […]

It's a subtle cue but a “*uniform* visa” is a visa allowing you to *enter* the Schengen area (see e.g. article 2 and article 24). This requirement therefore **does not apply to airport transit visas** (issued under article 26 and defined separately in article 2). Incidentally, references to “travel medical insurance” in other articles are qualified with the phrase “where applicable” (implicitly: because it does not apply to transit visas, diplomats, sea farers, etc.).

In any case, the insurance requirement only applies to visa holders and is part of the *visa* requirements (i.e. it's not directly an *entry* requirement). So, unless the consulate made a serious mistake, if you already have a visa and did not need to submit evidence of travel insurance, it means it wasn't required in your situation (with a small caveat: multiple-entry visa applications only require proof of insurance for the first trip but it's still required to have it for any subsequent trip). See also [Is medical insurance mandatory for entering the Schengen area if you are not required to have a visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47633/is-medical-insurance-mandatory-for-entering-the-schengen-area-if-you-are-not-req/53314#53314) for more details on this.