# Do Australian citizens need a letter of invitation to visit a Schengen and EU country for tourism?

Tags: schengen, paperwork, eu, visa-free-entry, australian-citizens

In other words, are there any requirements for the Australian citizens to visit Schengen area/EU for tourism purposes using the Visa Waiver Programme?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to be able to justify the purpose and conditions of your visit ([Schengen Borders Code 6(1)(c)](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A02016R0399-20190611)).  Unlike a visa applicant, however, who is required to submit documents supporting this justification in applying for a visa, the chance of your being asked for documents is exceedingly low.

Tourists sometimes -- or perhaps even usually -- plan their visits independently without having anyone to invite them.  In such cases an invitation letter isn't possible except to the extent that a hotel could issue one, but instead of requiring that, Schengen authorities are happy to see proof of a reservation.

A visa applicant who *is* staying with a friend or acquaintance will want to include a letter from that person acknowledging this fact, in order to satisfy the visa officer that accommodations have been arranged.  Border officers, in the other hand, don't often look at the accommodation arrangements in detail.  If you *are* visiting someone, you won't need a letter.  In the unlikely event that immigration officers are skeptical, you might invite them to call your host on the phone.

In terms of both accommodation and departure from the Schengen area (where people sometimes erroneously think that an onward ticket is required for entry) all you need is to show credibly that you *can* arrange it.  In other words, you need money or a credit card.  Even there, you won't likely be asked to show that you have them unless perhaps you're particularly young.  Dress well, look affluent, and you're unlikely to receive much scrutiny.

It's unfortunate that these decisions may be influenced by the traveler's personal appearance, but it's nonetheless the case.  If you look non-European then you may want to pay a little more attention to having documentation available in case you're asked for it.  But don't volunteer anything other than your passport, lest you appear overeager, which can also arouse suspicion.

Comment: I see. What about financial data? Is this true and applies?: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/90949/does-the-money-requirement-for-schengen-visa-also-apply-to-visa-free-citizens?rq=1

Comment: @SirMuffington yes, it's true and it applies, which is why I mentioned "look affluent": doing so may reduce your chance of being asked to demonstrate your financial resources.  But don't dress up so much that you look uncomfortable, because that's probably an even bigger red flag.  To be clear, you may be asked to prove that you have sufficient resources for your trip, but for most people, the chance of actually being asked is very small.  I don't know of any cases where it happened.

Answer (score 7):

No, Australian citizens do not need a letter of invitation to visit a Schengen country.

Furthermore, as [noted](https://www.smartraveller.gov.au/before-you-go/the-basics/schengen) by the Australian government, "Australians don't need a visa to travel to countries in the Schengen Area for up to 90 days in any 180-day period... [for] tourism and holidays." The linked [government FAQ](https://www.smartraveller.gov.au/before-you-go/the-basics/schengen) covers the practical requirements.

Comment: Not needing a visa is not the same as not having to meet the criteria specified in the Schengen Borders Code, which are largely the same regardless of whether a visa is required.

Comment: Updated for clarity; a letter of invitation is not required. The specific criteria for entry in each Schengen country are included in the linked government FAQ.

Comment: I looked at that link and I don't see any mention of the Schengen Borders Code requirements about "purpose and conditions" or "means of subsistence," so it's not really "the full requirements."  But the absence of any mention of those requirements underscores very well how rarely any Australian traveler will ever be challenged on that basis, much less experience trouble at the border.

Comment: @phoog The linked FAQ from the Australian government covers purposes/reasons on the main page and goes pretty in-depth on country specific pages about visa requirements, health, local laws, embassy contacts, etc. It is written for a traveler rather than an attorney, but it is what the Australian government views as sufficient information for an Australian citizen. I have changed "full" requirements to "practical" requirements; in practice, it should be quite adequate as a source.