# Visiting Germany with Ukrainian biometric passport

Tags: visas, schengen, biometric-passports, ukrainian-citizens

I'm planning a one week vacation in Germany and have the new format Ukrainian biometric passport. I understand that Ukrainian nationals with the biometric passport no longer require a visa to enter Schengen states for vacation / holiday purposes. Can anybody confirm if this is correct and I need any other documentation for border control, such as letter of invitation, proof of accommodation, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's correct. You can check that with [the official announcement](http://europa.eu/rapid/press-release_STATEMENT-17-1270_en.htm) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Ukrainian_citizens) (which also provides link to a database airlines use to deal with these kinds of things).

In principle, the requirements for visa-free visits are almost the same than for visa holders (with one major exception: [travel health insurance is not required if you don't need a visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47633/is-medical-insurance-mandatory-for-entering-the-schengen-area-if-you-are-not-req)). In practice, border guards seldom spend more than a minute interviewing travellers and do not check any of this in detail. But they can legally deny entry if they are not satisfied that you have a valid purpose, sufficient financial means, etc. and all the documents you would use to establish that when applying for a visa could be useful if you are challenged at the border.